# Вопрос по POST запросу

Tags: php, post

не понимаю как сделать проверку.
У меня есть код

```
if($_POST['recover'])
{

  $res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `pEmail` = '{$_POST['email']}' AND `Name` = '{$_POST['username']}'")->num_rows;
  if($res >= 1) 
  {
    //успех
  } 
  else
  {
    //почта или имя не найдено, выводим ошибку.
  }
}
```

У меня есть в базе еще pEmailActive 1 - актив, 0 - не актив.
Мне надо чтобы если 1 актив проходило до успеха, если 0 не актив выдавало ошибку.

Comment: Не нужно анулировать текст вопроса. В качестве благодарности достаточно поставить зёлёную галочку на ответе и проголосовать за ответ. Смысл системы SO - что бы тот, кто задаст такой же вопрос как у вас - смог найти и вопрос и ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вытягиваете строку, если такая существует и проверяете значение нужного вам поля, примерно следующим образом

```
if($_POST['recover'])
{

  $res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `pEmail` = '{$_POST['email']}' AND `Name` = '{$_POST['username']}'");
  if($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
       if($row["pEmailActive"] == 1){
          //success
       }
    }
}
//not success
```

Если нужно с прошлой проверкой то примерно следующим образом...

```
if($_POST['recover'])
{
  $res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `pEmail` = '{$_POST['email']}' AND `Name` = '{$_POST['username']}'");
  if($res->num_rows > 0){
     $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
     if($row["pEmailActive"] == 1){
       //success
     } else {
      //false
     }
  }else {
   //почта или имя не найдено, выводим ошибку.
  }
}
```